# Security Group not working with ec2 which is not in vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have an instance m3 large both the instance and the security group are outside vpc. I'm running a simple server application at port 5674. the port 5674 is open to all in the security group. still my client code is not able to reach the port when given the public ip. 
The error it gives is **EHOSTUNREACH**

At Server side this is the response of

**netstat -atn**

`tcp6       0      0 :::5674                 :::*                    LISTEN`

At Client

**netcat -v myPublicIp 5674**

`connect to myPublicIp port 5674 (tcp) failed: No route to host`

what could be the reason ?
 same client program works if I give *localhost* as the host.

It doesn't even work from the same system .

Comment: I think you should create security group in VPC where your instances are running on.

Comment: EHOSTUNREACH - the route is not found for that particular host.

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your configuration? Is your instance in a public subnet or a private subnet? Does it work if you try to connect from a computer that is on the Internet (outside of AWS)?

Comment: the instance is not in VPC . its publicly accessible . the ports are not working from outside . even inside if i give the public ip as the hostname .

Comment: @KumareshBabu yes it gives EHOSTUNREACH - the route is not found for that particular host.

Comment: @mehnaazm Based upon the question, you have to create security group in a VPC where EC2 instance are running on. Replace new security group with existing security group in an EC2 instance.

Comment: both are outside vpc the SC and the instance

Answer (score 0):

The only case an instance is outside VPC is EC2-classic. If this is your case then consider moving to EC2-VPC because you have a lot of restrictions.

If you create the account within the last year or two then your instance IS in VPC and there's just no way to do otherwise.

Check your subnet, all SGs, NACLs. If you can SSH there from your desktop without a jump box then routing is OK, otherwise check it too.